# How to extract new window with custom widgets inside from Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to extract different panels of my browser to a new window, in a way that docking panels are working, but with the difference that you can extract a panel outside your browser. Is there something available in Flutter for that?

Kind Regards!